# Sequelize.js virtual attributes from HSTORE

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, hstore

I am trying to implement HSTORE translation in my models, is there a way to make it work without JS getters, something like this:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('whatever', {
    title_en: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: "title -> 'en'",
    },
  })
})
```

### What do you expect to happen?

So the actual SQL is:

```
SELECT "id", title -> 'en' AS "title_en" FROM "whatever";
```

### What is actually happening?

Instead of:

```
SELECT "id", "title -> 'en'" AS "title_en" FROM "whatever";
```

Comment: try changing `field: "title -> 'en'"` to `field: {title: "en"}` ?..

Comment: That causes an error, probably have to write a plugin or something.

Comment: no,no I just thought about monkey hack. hstore attribute->'keyname' syntaxis is same for json, so I thought to mochkup json qry with sequelize so it would generate same attribute->'keyname' . aparently it didn't work. Or I did json qry wrong...

Comment: Maybe it generated 'keyname=>5'::hstore->>'keyname' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the field as a literal:

```
sequelize.define('whatever', {
  title_en: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: Sequelize.literal("title -> 'en'"),
  }
})
```

Which will produce the desired query

```
SELECT `id`, title -> 'en' AS `title_en`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `whatevers` AS `whatever` WHERE `whatever`.`id` = 1;
```